# Calling a variable in a different function without using global

Tags: python, function, variables, global, local

I'm trying to use a variable / list in a function that is defined in another function without making it global.

Here is my code:

```
def hi():
    hello = [1,2,3]
    print("hello")

def bye(hello):
    print(hello)

hi()
bye(hello)
```

At the moment I am getting the error that "hello" in "bye(hello)" is not defined.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: as it stands, `hello` is a name (read variable), local to the `hi` function. The best way, from what I can see, would be to assign `hello` in the global space (i.e. where you call the functions) and pass such variable as a parameter to the functions. Or, as suggested below, let `hi` return `hello`

Comment: you can't resolve this, local variable to a function can't be seen in an other : it's all the interest of local variables !

Comment: I believe this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), since what you are attempting does not adhere to any good practice. What are you trying to achieve? What is the reason for wanting to perform such odd coding?

Comment: @Pynchia The code I used above was just something thrown together. I'm  really just trying to access a list defined in one function in a different function without making it global. Kinda similar to the XY problem :P

Comment: alright, I thought I might try and help you solve the design conundrum :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't want to use a global variable, your best option is just to call `bye(hello)` from within `hi()`.

```
def hi():
    hello = [1,2,3]
    print("hello")
    bye(hello)

def bye(hello):
    print(hello)

hi()
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the best method for me to do it. The code in the question was example code which I made up. I tried implementing your idea into my main code, but I am getting the same error for other variables in the function "bye" (Not called bye in my proper code). How can I solve this? @QuakeCore

Comment: You can try to send that other variable as an argument along with `hello`, or yet better to [use classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 5):

You need to return hello from your `hi` method.

By simply printing you are not able to gain access to what happens inside the `hi` method. Variables created inside a method remain within the scope of that method.

Information on variable scope in Python:

http://gettingstartedwithpython.blogspot.ca/2012/05/variable-scope.html

You return `hello` inside your `hi` method, then, when you call `hi`, you should store the result in a variable.

So, in `hi`, you return:

```
def hi():
    hello = [1,2,3]
    return hello
```

Then when you call your method, you store the result of `hi` in a variable:

```
hi_result = hi()
```

Then, you pass that variable to your `bye` method:

```
bye(hi_result)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried doing this, but I couldn't remember how to do it. Your answer certainly helped :P

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare global variables inside a function without `global`.You can do this

```
def hi():
    hello = [1,2,3]
    print("hello")
    return hello

def bye(hello):
    print(hello)

hi()
bye(hi())
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it sounds like you're trying to solve something that would be better off done a different way (see [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)
)

If hi and bye need to share different types of data, you might be better off using a class.  Ex:

```
class MyGreetings(object):
    hello = [1, 2, 3]

    def hi(self):
        print('hello')

    def bye(self):
        print(self.hello)
```

You could also do it with globals:

```
global hello

def hi():
    global hello
    hello = [1,2,3]
    print("hello")

def bye():
    print(hello)
```

or by having hi return a value:

```
def hi():
    hello = [1,2,3]
    print("hello")
    return hello

def bye():
    hello = hi()
    print(hello)
```

or you could have hi put hello on the hi function itself:

```
def hi():
    hello = [1,2,3]
    print("hello")
    hi.hello = hello


def bye():
    hello = hi.hello
    print(hello)
```

Now that said, the sketchy way to accomplish what you're asking would be to pull out the source code of hi(), and execute the body of the function within bye() and then pull out the variable hello:

```
import inspect
from textwrap import dedent


def hi():
    hello = [1,2,3]
    print("hello")

def bye():
    sourcelines = inspect.getsourcelines(hi)[0]
    my_locals = {}
    exec(dedent(''.join(sourcelines[1:])), globals(), my_locals)
    hello = my_locals['hello']
    print(hello)
```