# Python 3 : Rock, Paper, Scissor game - how to define counts for the wins and picks

Tags: python-3.x, count, counter, user-defined-functions

I'm new to Python. Need to create the game Rock, Paper, Scissors in Python 3 that prints out at the end of the game:

```
The number of rounds the computer has won.
The number of rounds the user has won.
The number of rounds that ended in a tie
The number of times the user selected each weapon (Rock, Paper, Scissors).
```

**Note**: Computer should select the weapon most likely to beat the user, based on the user’s previous choice of weapons, but its choice will not be displayed until later so the user doesn’t see it. For that computer keeps a count of how many times the user has selected each weapon (Rock, Paper or Scissors).

Example, if the user has selected Rock and Paper 3 times each and Scissors only 1 time, or if the user has selected each of the weapons an equal number of times, then there is no single weapon that has been used most frequently by the user; in this case the computer may select any of the weapons.

My code is next:

```
# Import random function
import random

# After the round ask the user if he/she would like to play the game again
def display_intro():
    print("Welcome to Rock, Paper and Scissors Game!")
    play_game = input("Would you like to play with me?\n"
                  "y/n").lower()
    if play_game == "y" or play_game == "yes" or play_game == "Y":
        print("Let\'s start playing!")
        get_comp_choice()
    elif play_game == "n" or play_game == "no" or play_game == "N":
        print("Thanks for playing")
        print("Computer won", compWinCt, "times.")"" \
        print("User won", userWinCt, "times.")
        print("Draw games count is: ",drawCt)
        print("User picked Rock", userRockCt, "times.")
        print("User picked Paper", userPaperCt, "times.")
        print("User picked Scissors", userScissors, "times.")
        quit()
    else:
        print("That's now a valid choice. Please try again!")
    display_intro()


# define random choice pick
def get_random_choice():
    comp_choice = random.randint(1, 3)
    if comp_choice == 1:
        comp_choice = "r"
    elif comp_choice == 2:
        comp_choice = "p"
    elif comp_choice == 3:
        comp_choice = "s"
    return comp_choice

# define computer choice base on what user has chosen in previous rounds
def get_comp_choice():
    if userRockCt == 0 and userPaperCt == 0 and userScissorsCt == 0:
        return get_random_choice()
    else:
        if (userRockCt > userPaperCt) and (userRockCt > userScissorsCt):
           return comp_choice == "r"
        elif (userPaperCt > userRockCt) and (userPaperCt > userScissorsCt):
            return comp_choice == "p"
        elif (userScissorsCt > userPaperCt) and (userScissorsCt > userRockCt):
            return comp_choice == "s"

def main():
while True:
    # set count for a zero
    userRockCt = 0
    userPaperCt = 0
    userScissorsCt = 0
    compWinCt = 0
    userWinCt = 0
    drawCt = 0
    # Get computer choice
    comp_choice = get_comp_choice()
    # Get user choice from the input
    user_choice = input("Please enter from the menue: \n"
                        "r for rock,"
                        "p for paper"
                        "s for scissors"
                        "q to quit")

    # Check who has won /lost or if the game is draw
    # Get the count for how many times user picke Rock, Paper or Scissors
    # Get the count for how many times won computer and user and the count for the draw
    while comp_choice == "r":
        if user_choice == "r":
            print("This is a DRAW. You chose Rock and Computer chose Rock.")
            userRockCt += 1
            drawCt += 1
        elif user_choice == "p":
            print("YOU WIN. You chose Paper and Computer chose Rock. Paper covers Rock.")
            userPaperCt += 1
            userWinCt += 1
        elif user_choice == "s":
            print("YOU LOSE. You chose Scissors and Computer chose Rock. Rock breaks Scissors.")
            userScissorsCt += 1
            compWinCt += 1
        else:
            print("Try again")
        display_intro()

    while comp_choice == "p":
        if user_choice == "r":
            print("YOU LOSE. You chose Rock and Computer chose Paper. Paper covers Rock.")
            userRockCt += 1
            compWinCt += 1
        elif user_choice == "p":
            print("This is a DRAW. You chose Rock and Computer chose Rock.")
            userPaperCt += 1
            drawCt += 1
        elif user_choice == "s":
            print("YOU WIN. You chose Scissors and Computer chose Paper. Scissors cut Paper.")
            userScissorsCt += 1
            userWinCt += 1
        display_intro()

    while comp_choice == "s":
        if user_choice == "r":
            print("YOU WIN. You chose Rock and Computer chose Scissors. Rock breaks Scissors.")
            userRockCt += 1
            userWinCt += 1
        elif user_choice == "p":
            print("YOU LOSE. You chose Paper and Computer chose Scissors. Scissors cut Paper.")
            userPaperCt += 1
            compWinCt += 1
        elif user_choice == "s":
            print("This is a DRAW. You chose Scissors and Computer chose Scissors.")
            userScissorsCt += 1
            drawCt += 1
        display_intro()


main()
```

I don't know if I am misplacing the order of define function or missing something. When I run the code I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../Test", line 123, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/.../Test", line 64, in main
    comp_choice = get_comp_choice()
  File "C:/Users/.../Test", line 43, in get_comp_choice
    if userRockCt == 0 and userPaperCt == 0 and userScissorsCt == 0:
NameError: name 'userRockCt' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And just looking at the code I can tell that the same issue will be with userPaperCt, userScissorsCt at get_comp_choice

and at def display_intro() with compWinCt, userWinCt and DrawCt

I've seen some examples of using global but I'm trying to avoid using it.

Comment: I think userRockCt is only localised within the main function, as the variable exists only within that scope.  Making it global would solve this error, however, if you don't want to use it. You will have to pass this local variable in main function to that  get_comp_choice as a parameter. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389998/calling-a-variable-in-a-different-function-without-using-global) will be useful.

Comment: @ShamveelAhammed Thank you very much for your respond! Question, if I decide to use global functions - how does it work?  I just assign userRockCt and etc to it?

Comment: Yes. Just declare the variable outside any functions, e.g after import, then just declare it global within a function (that will make it accessible for other functions). Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them) for a example use.

Comment: @ShamveelAhammed thank you for your answer! I'll try out your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Declaring 'userRockCt' as a global variable would solve this issue.

```
# Import random function
import random

# Declaring the variable here
userRockCt = 0

# Rest of the code goes here

def main():
while True:
   # Declaring the variable as global here
   # set count for a zero
   global userRockCt

   # rest of your code

main()
```